# How to create custom post page in WordPress?

Tags: posts, page-template

I want to create a post page template for my website.

I am currently using the theme's default post page. I created a template (Template 1) with wp-bakery in  pages section with JegTheme addons :
[image: template]

When a users enters a blog post, they should see that post with the template that I prepared.

I tried to change it from settings -> reading -> Post page: Template 1

Comment: Ask the JegTheme's support forum or support system or developers... ...WPSE is intended to address developer issues with WordPress itself, not as a 'How To' guide for third party plugins and themes.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.